# All Views are not Loading in Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I load the default page (`http://localhost/MVCP/Home/index`) it loads correctly, whereas when I load another view (`http://localhost/MVCP/Home/Create`) it doesn't load. How can I fix this?

My `Create` action in `HomeController`:

```
[HttpGet] [ActionName("Create")] public void Create() { }
```

Comment: Do you have an action in your `HomeController` called `Create`? Show us your code for your controller.

Comment: @adrianbanks, Yes, [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("Create")]
        public void Create()
        {
            
        }

Comment: can you share code of Create action in Home controller? Also what is the structure of Home folder under Views folder?

Comment: @Nirman, No code in as above in Get. Folder Structure is like View -> Home -> [Create.cshtml then Index.cshtml]..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q:** Do you have an action in your `HomeController` called `Create`?
>   **A:** Yes,  `[HttpGet] [ActionName("Create")] public void Create() { }`

Your action return value is `void` and probably you even didn't write anything in response. change the signature of action to have an `ActionResult` as return a `View`.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

To learn more:

- [Adding a View](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view)
   in [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) Series.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is no view you have created so far and it seems your controller are inside area folder so have u checked your routeing too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Action should return ActionResult or ViewResult but certainly not "void" as you have written currently.

and also you should write

```
return view();
```

in Create action